# Pagination Laravel using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, pagination, livesearch

** I need to show pagination when show data
this is my controller**
I try to show pagination with laravel but it is not work
How I can solve this proplem ??I try to show pagination with laravel but it is not work
How I can solve this proplem ??

```
public function showJobApplicant(Request $request)
{
    $job = Job::findOrFail($request->id);
    $applicants = DB::table('applicant')
        ->select('*')
        ->join('job_app', 'applicant.id', '=', 'job_app.applicant_oid')
        ->where('job_app.job_oid', $request->id)->paginate(2);
 
    return response()->json([
        'applicants' => $applicants,
    ]);
}
```

and this is javascript part

```
<script>
    $('#search3').on('keyup', function(){
        $('#form3').submit(false);
        search3();
    });
    search3();
    function search3(){

        var keyword3 = $('#search3').val();
        $.post('{{ route("showJobApplicant") }}',
            {
                _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                keyword3:keyword3,
                id: {{$job->id}}
            },
            function(data){
                table_post_row3(data);
            });
    }
    // table row with ajax
    function table_post_row3(res){
        let htmlView = '';
        if(res.applicants.length <= 0){
            htmlView+= `
  <tr>
  <td colspan="9" class="text-center">لا يوجد بيانات لعرضها</td>
  </tr>`;
        }
        var color  = 'primary';
        var status = 'تحت الدراسة';
                <?php $check = false;
                echo $check;
                ?>
        for(let i = 0; i < res.applicants.length; i++){
             var sex = 'أنثى';
            if(res.applicants[i].sex == 101)
                sex = 'ذكر';
            var url = 'showApplicantInfo/'+ res.applicants[i].id_num;
            htmlView += `
  <tr>
     <td>`+ (i+1) +`</td>
     <td>`+res.applicants[i].f_name+' '+res.applicants[i].m_name+ ' '+ res.applicants[i].s_name+' '+res.applicants[i].l_name+`</td>
     <td>`+res.applicants[i].id_num+`</td>
     <td>`+res.applicants[i].bdate.split(" ")[0]+`</td>
     <td>`+sex+`</td>
     <td>`+res.applicants[i].mobile_num+`</td>
  </tr>`;
        }
        $('#applicants').html(htmlView);
    }
</script>
```

and view like this

```
<div class="col-12 table-responsive" id="kt_apps_projects_2">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form id="form3" method="POST">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="البحث برقم الهوية" id="search3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <span class="input-group-text" >
  <i class="flaticon-search-1"></i>
  </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="text-success">#</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-success">الاسم الرباعي</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-success">رقم الهوية</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-success">تاريخ الميلاد</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-success">الجنس</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-success">رقم الجوال</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-success">الحالة</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-success">عرض التفاصيل</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="applicants">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

how can I show pagination, please??

answer me on this problem

Comment: What happens when you do `dd($applicants);` you should get pagination links since you paginated the query

Comment: yes i got pagination when type `  console.log(res.applicants);` show in console `{current_page: 1, data: Array(2), first_page_url: 'http://localhost:8000/admin/showJobApplicant?page=1', from: 1, last_page: 2, …}

last_page
: 
2
last_page_url
: 
"http://localhost:8000/admin/showJobApplicant?page=2"
links
: 
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
next_page_url
: 
"http://localhost:8000/admin/showJobApplicant?page=2"
path
: 
"http://localhost:8000/admin/showJobApplicant"
per_page
: 
2
prev_page_url
: 
null
to
: 
2
total
: 
3
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object`

Comment: the pagination work but i dont know how display it in view, can help me?